# ¿Cómo hacer suma condicional en Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

Estoy realizando un reporte con SAP crystal report 16 y deseo realizar una sumatoria de un campo llamado  `sueldos` siempre y cuando el campo  `Cod_Proyecto` sea diferente de `"000"`